# Add WordPress Blogs in Another web site

Tags: vb.net, wordpress

I have a blog page (developed in WordPress) and have a website (Developed in VbCommerce). My requirement is that we have to add latest three blogs into Our WebSite. So please someone tell me how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) plugin. And use `per_page` to get latest three posts. Then on your VBcommerce website, you can show latest blog posts from WordPress through `CURL`.

Comment: Thanks man. I installed WP REST API plugin from Plugins in word press and use that. All working now.